# Firebase Security Permissions

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm having trouble with a user who is trying to access someone else's email. I'm getting `E/ContactsFragment.java: Finding email failed. DatabaseError: Permission denied`. It's also worth noting that the email gets checked before going into the database and also the email that I inputted is the same as the one in the database.
Basically, what I'm trying to do is for `user1` to find the `user2`'s email. From there, I will do something with the email.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users":{
      ".indexOn": ["email"],
      "$uid":{
        ".read": "auth !== null",
        "email":{
          ".write": "auth !== null && $uid === auth.uid",
          ".validate": "newData.isString()"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my data structure:
[image: database structure]

Here's my code that is trying to access the email:

```
final String TAG = "ContactsFragment.java";
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").orderByChild("email").equalTo(email).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // some code
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.e(TAG,"Finding email failed. " + databaseError);
            }
        });
```

How can I fix it? Am I missing something important?

Comment: The only thing in your current rule configuration that would deny a user read access to child nodes under `/users` would be if that user is not authenticated (as per `".read": "auth !== null"`), so you'll need to make sure the user is authenticated before attempting to access the data.

Comment: Well this function is ran after the login activity and I was able to check if the user was able to authenticate himself through the login activity. So I doubt that the user is unauthenticated

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. You can confirm that a user is authenticated by doing [`FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#getCurrentUser()) which will return `null` if the user is not authenticated, or a `FirebaseUser` instance if they are authenticated.

Comment: Yes. It's not null when I do that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your rules are only granting read access to children under the `/users` node, but not the `/users` node itself, which will deny them from querying the list.

If you move your `.read` rule outside of the `$uid` child, it will allow users to query the the `/users` list node:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users":{
      ".indexOn": ["email"],
      ".read": "auth !== null",
      "$uid":{
        "email":{
          ".write": "auth !== null && $uid === auth.uid",
          ".validate": "newData.isString()"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Queries are attached to the list node rather than child nodes under the list, so the `.read` permission needs to be granted on the list itself. For example, your query is being attached to the `/users` node:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").orderByChild("email").equalTo(email)[...]
```

This is because [rules are applied in an atomic manner](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters), and therefore a `.read` rule at a deep path will not allow access to a shallower path.